# Android ImageView onClick

Tags: android, image, button, onclick, imageview

I am new with Android development.
I have 5 images in array and i want to change pictures on click so here is what i did but pictures won't change.

```
 int[] images = {R.drawable.pic_1,
        R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3,
        R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5};
     int plus = 0 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap bImage ;

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plus++;
            }
        });

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plus--;
            }
        });


            bImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),images[plus]);
            img.setImageBitmap(bImage);



    }
```

Anyone has any idea that could work this way ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 int[] images = {R.drawable.pic_1,
        R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3,
        R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5};
     int plus = 0 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap bImage ;

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if(plus<4){
                plus++;
                img.setBackgroundResource(images[plus]);
              }
            }
        });

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(plus>0){
                plus--;
                img.setBackgroundResource(images[plus]);
                }
            }
        });


            bImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),images[plus]);
            img.setImageBitmap(bImage);



    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot !! It works but img.setImageBitmap(bImage); is useless since it collieded with setbackgroundresource and also i need to fix app getting crashed when plus is less than zero or bigger than array length...

Comment: Also if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct.:)

Comment: i tried this fix for array bounds but it keeps crashing i will find out something ... But thanks for first part it was much harder :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get well versed with Android Activity Lifecycle. A basic understanding will be very helpful for you to begin with android development.

OnCreate method is called only once, when the activity is created. Hence, in your onclicklisteners you should also put code for changing image bitmap. So your onclicklistener should look like:

```
plus++;
bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),images[plus]);
img.setImageBitmap(bImage);
```

This is just a solution to the above problem, but I would highly recommend you to go through basic android concepts to kick start on your app development without getting stuck at trivial issues.

Good luck.!

Answer (score 0):

Set a global Variable

```
private int imageclick=0;
```

and use the following logic

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bImage ;

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bImage ;

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

if(imageclick==0)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_1);
imageclick=1;
}
else if(imageclick==1)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_2);
imageclick=2;
}
else if(imageclick==2)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_3);
imageclick=3;
}
else if(imageclick==3)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_4);
imageclick=4;
}
else if(imageclick==4)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_5);
imageclick=0;
}
        }
    });

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

if(imageclick==0)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_4);
imageclick=4;
}
else if(imageclick==1)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_3);
imageclick=0;
}
else if(imageclick==2)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_2);
imageclick=1;
}
else if(imageclick==3)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_1);
imageclick=2;
}
else if(imageclick==4)
{
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_5);
imageclick=3;
}
      }
        }
    });


        bImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),images[plus]);
        img.setImageBitmap(bImage);



}
```

this logic may work for you